# Can any combination of unit and item lose the first few rounds of TFT?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

In the current season of Teamfight Tactics (Season 2), the first three rounds begin fighting minions which don't normally pose much of a threat.

Assuming you have as many units on your board as possible, is it possible with any combination of units to lose any of these first three rounds?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, what you have requested is not possible.

Comment: Hi, trying to bypass the 30 character limit by adding unnecessary text isn't acceptable. In order to reach the limit legitimately, please try to give some more details. Why isn't this possible?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 it's just not, they literally don't lose. Not sure what there is to say. Also it's a fortunate thing since you don't want to lose.